# Counting primes less than n in Python

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I implemented (a refinement of) the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Overview) for counting primes less than a given number n. This is a coding exercise from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-primes/). The class `Solution` is of course not necessary but only for the purpose of submitting the code on LeetCode.

The code passes the tests when n is not very large, but "Time Limit Exceeded" when the input is 858232. I am looking for ways to speed up the code.

```
class Solution(object):
    def countPrimes(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """

        # Sieve of Eratosthenes
        if n <= 2:
            return 0
        
        sieve = [False, False] + [True] * (n - 2)
        
        for p in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
            if sieve[p]:
                for x in range(p * p, n, p):
                    sieve[x] = False
        return sum(sieve)
```

Comment: FYI I submitted your solution a couple of times on LeetCode and it seems to succeed. It says 83.93% faster than other Python3 solutions.

Comment: @Marc: thanks for that. It is indeed strange that when submitting several times, the code passes all the tests in some submission. In the Time-Limit-Exceeded one, it complains with the mentioned input 858232.

Answer (score 1):

The `math` library also has the `isqrt(n)` function, that calculates the integer sqrt. Use it instead of `int(sqrt(n))`.

The most obvious way to speed up your solution is to stop testing all the even numbers.

This checks all the numbers >= 2:

```
for p in range(2, int(sqrt(n)) + 1):
    if sieve[p]:
```

But the first step eliminates all even numbers > 2. So you need to test them.

```
# handle 2 separately
for x in range(2 * 2, n, 2):
        sieve[x] = False

# now just check the odd numbers
for p in range(3, isqrt(n) + 1, 2):
    if sieve[p]:
        # p*p + p is even, so we can skip it
        for x in range(p * p, n, 2*p):
            sieve[x] = False
```

Of course, you could just initialize the `sieve` with all the even numbers > 2 set to False:

```
sieve = [False, True] * ((n + 1) // 2)
sieve[1] = False
sieve[2] = True

if `n` is odd, then sieve is too long
if n&1: sieve.pop()
```

All together, it runs twice as fast for `n = 858233`:

```
def countPrimes(n):
    """
    :type n: int
    :rtype: int
    """

    # Sieve of Eratosthenes
    if n <= 2:
        return 0

    sieve = [False, True] * ((n + 1) // 2)
    sieve[1] = False
    sieve[2] = True
    if n&1: sieve.pop()

    for p in range(3, isqrt(len(sieve))+1 , 2):
        if sieve[p]: 
            for x in range(p * p, n, 2*p):
                sieve[x] = False
                
    return sum(sieve)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, in addition to considering all even numbers > 2 set to False, multiples of 2 and 3 can be excluded to further speed up

```
def countPrimes(n):
    if n<=2:
        return 0
    if n<6:
        return n//3+n//5
    dimv=n//6
    sieve5mod6 = [True] * (dimv+1)
    sieve1mod6 = [True] * (dimv+1)
    imax=int((n**0.5)/6)+1
    for i in range(1,imax+1):
        if sieve5mod6[i]:
            imin=6*i*i
            pi=6*i-1
            sieve5mod6[imin::pi]=[False]*((dimv-imin)//pi+1)
            sieve1mod6[imin-2*i::pi]=[False]*((dimv-imin+2*i)//pi+1)
        if sieve1mod6[i]:
            imin=6*i*i
            pi=6*i+1
            sieve5mod6[imin::pi]=[False]*((dimv-imin)//pi+1)
            sieve1mod6[imin+2*i::pi]=[False]*((dimv-imin-2*i)//pi+1)

    #since sieve5m6[0]=True and sieve1m6[0]=True is exploited to consider 2 and 3 in the count
    #for an exact result it is necessary to distinguish the different values ??of n%6
    if n%6>1: return sum(sieve5mod6)+sum(sieve1mod6)
    return sum(sieve5mod6)+sum(sieve1mod6[:-1:])
```